# New to IOS, app on my phone is different then simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I got my IOS developers today and just did all the Provision Profiles and I just ran my app on my phone for the first time. For some reason one of the backgrounds in my app works on the simulator but doesn't show up on the iPhone. Can anyone explain this?

Edit:

The Background is a UIImageView set to the index of 0. When the app is launched it starts with the background that works and when a button is pressed it changes to a different UIImage that doessnt work on my phone.

Comment: A little more detail will be necessary. What type of background? In what view? What is the view hierarchy like?

Comment: @psoft please look at my edit. Ask if more info is needed...

Comment: Can we have pictures, code, anything??

Comment: The simulator screen has a background and the IPhone has blank one. Code is pretty much when button is pressed: background.image = myUImage;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should double-check your resources. You should note that while the simulator appears to be case-insensitive, the device is case-sensitive! If your image file is called "myAwesomeImage.png" and your code says…

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myawesomeimage.png"];
```

…it may work on the simulator, but it won't on the device.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with the way your resources are copied. Make sure all the necessary image files are included in both the device and simulator targets.